# Investigation of specific lines of code on github

Tags: javascript, git

hey guys i was just debugging a Jquery carasoul plugin and came across the following lines of code ::

```
 $next.addClass(type)
 $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
```

ofcourse , by themselves they mean very little , so you can have a look at the source on git [here.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L147)(check line 147).

now , my question s not what those lines of code are doing but , my question is :

sometimes when your going through a github repository , you come across a few lines of code which by themselves make very little sense and even if these lines of code are debugged , they still persists to make very little sense , the lines of code above are an example of what i am trying to say.

now in such a scenario, a person is left with only one option and that is to check for comments on the git repo for that specific line of code , but my question is "how do you go about doing that" ?? . i tried the "BLAME" button , but that litterally gives me no info as to why those lines of code were added . So which place on git do i go to , to find out "Why these lines of code were added ??" .

Thank you.

Tenali.

Comment: Better suited on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)? If this was a member of my team I was working with, I'd first of all read the commit message/ any comments around the piece of code I was unsure you (as you have done). Then if i still didn't understand it, maybe follow the code through, and see what it does, try to identify its purpose and what it's doing. If i still wasn't sure what was going on, I'd attempt to ask someone that is more familiar with the project, preferably the guy that added that portion of code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the blame button is probably as much info as you're going to get - it shows the comment left for that revision on the left along with the author.  Unless the code itself is commented, the only other way is asking the author themselves.

[image]

Comment: i saw that popup too , is that information about the line of code i have selected , or is it something else ?

Comment: That's the information provided by the author when they checked in those lines, along with all the other lines affected.  Personally, I don't add a comment on _every single line of code I write_ as to why it's there - it's usually part of a larger change which is documented.